# Terminal dies and restarts when I try to import fancyimpute

Tags: fancyimpute

I am using ubuntu 18.04. When I try to import fancy impute in jupyter notebook using python 3 suddenly the kernal dies and restarts. PLease help.

Comment: ... are you aware that your question is way too broad? Please specify your problem.

Comment: Hi, I am trying to import fancyimpute package in jupyter notebook. Everytime I run the command there is a popup which says "The kernel appears to have died. It will restart automatically.". I have tried updating all the packages but nothing seems to help.

Comment: I have same issue with Spyder. Kernels dies when importing following: `from fancyimpute import KNN`